# Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTFoundation.DevicePlatformMapping

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Getting this warning when simulating an iPhone 4 in OS X using the Cocos2d-x engine. It's being spit into the terminal and I have to perform a Control-C to take back the terminal. The entirety of the warning is this:

`ios-sim-xcode6[30350:2161521] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-9542/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/PlugInManager/DVTPlugInManager.m:259
Details:  Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTFoundation.DevicePlatformMapping
Object:   <DVTPlugInManager: 0x7faa9a51dda0>
Method:   -extensionPointWithIdentifier:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faa9a40bdd0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.`